# How can I make two shortcuts icon for running split Activity after install

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android eclipse project with two split activity. I want to make two shortcut icons on my device after I run it on my device. I want to run `Activity1` when I click `[icon1]` and to run `Activity2` when I click `[icon2]`. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Add the category as `Launcher` and action as `Main` in the `<intent-filter>` for both of your activities in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to show two different icons in the Android menu.

```
<activity android:name="Activity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="Activity2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```